# Silverlight dynamic localization

Tags: .net, silverlight-4.0

I'm fairly new to both Silverlight and localization, and I've seen many examples on the web about this, but all of them seem to embed the resource file in the .xap file, so my question basically is: **is this the only way? isn't there anyway to have the .resx files outside the .xap file and achieve proper localization?.**

My goal is to create an interface to let certain user edit the localized values, so I don't have to rebuild and redeploy the app every time a value is changed (usually upon request) and while I could use a database based approach, I wanted to try and see if this was possible using resource files since there are some other UI issues to consider (like some strings being longer in one language) and I think resource files can help me to handle those better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facing some difficulties, I have written an article about this recently, I think it might help you, you can find it there: http://mysharpsnippets.wordpress.com/2011/11/04/silverlight-dynamic-localization/

Comment: +1, It's a nice tutorial, but I think it doesn't answer my question (essentially, the part in bold in my original post)

Comment: How doesn't it answer your question ?
"Is this the only way?" -No
"Isn't there anyway to have the .resx files outside the .xap file" - Yes
"and achieve proper localization?" -Yep, works pretty fine

Comment: Ok, then I will check it out again and do a clean test project. I blame it on being Friday :P

Comment: No worries, for my part the localization was a lot of struggle and frustration until I got it to work ;)